# SSO Login without Page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, single-sign-on, disqus

I need to know how I can process the SSO login without reloading the page.

My sample link is http://abmprograms.com/tdr/disqus.php

When I click on the first option to login a pop-up opens, if I either try to login with below details (see my comment below) or close it the page reloads.

Is there anyway to prevent this?

Comment: The credentials are, 
Username : mufleeh@gmail.com
Password : XBaew,FN

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using, jquery. Have you tried using modal forms: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form 
You can control the login form post using javascript which would let you control the modal form behavior.

Comment: Hi Jitendra, thanks for your reply. I thought the same but Disqus pops-out a window which we have no control of and it always reloads the page when we close it. 

This is how we set the login/logout pages.

 // This adds the custom login/logout functionality
      this.sso = {
            name:    "The Daily Reminder",
            button:  "content/images/disqus-tdr-logo.png",
            url:     "comment-login.php",
            logout:  "logout.php" 
      };